# LDAP queries using UWP on Windows 10 IoT

Tags: ldap, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

After several hours of searching it appears that there is no way to query a local LDAP directory (Microsoft Active Directory or otherwise) from a UWP app.

This seems like a rather bizarre hole in the UWP offering, and so I'm hopeful that I'm just missing the obvious.

What (if anything) is the functional equivalent of System.DirectoryServices in the Universal Windows Platform world?

Comment: Unfortunately this feature is not implemented in UWP yet. [There's](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705/suggestions/12556779) some votes on this feature request.

Answer (score 2):

This thread is a little older, but you have 3 options today:

1. Use the [Windows Compatibility Pack for .NetCore](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/16/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/).
2. Use the Desktop Bridge to create a .Net component that does your LDAP queries. See [this](http://aka.ms/desktopbridge) for more information.
3. If you can, move to the Microsoft Graph - [link](https://github.com/search?q=uwp+sample+user:microsoftgraph&type=Repositories) to samples.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

System.DirectoryServices is not available in the UWP, but if you are using sideloading for your app then you can use Brokered windows component to get or create the details required through a endpoint in it.

You can get it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps).

Comment: is there any other options available like a Nuget package for UWP ? I do not intend to sideload my app