# Compiling and including OpenLDAP libraries into a C++/CX UWP app

Tags: c++, windows, uwp, openldap, c++-cx

I'm developing a VoIP application (C++/CX) targeting the Universal Windows Platform. At some point, the app needs to query an LDAP server who is keeping a phonebook directory.

As I [couldn't find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701898/ldap-queries-using-uwp-on-windows-10-iot) an equivalent of the System.DirectoryServices framework for the UWP, I tried to compile the libraries myself with no success so far. The thing is every OpenLDAP doc on how to build the project for Windows seems to be really outdated. But looking into the sources, I see they provide sample solutions up until Visual Studio vc15, so it is definitely not abandoned.

I tried to build both projects (lber and ldap) and run into many dependency problems. I needed to build Cyrus SASL libraries and OpenSSL, then put all the include paths into the project and link the enerated library objects until I successfully got both libs (olber32_a_debug.lib & oldap32_a_debug.lib) to build.

Finally, I tried to include them into my app project. Still running into some linker issues regarding cyrus.

[Linker Issues LNK2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYAeG.jpg)

```
unresolved external symbol __imp__sasl_version referenced in function _ldap_int_sasl_init [oldap32_a_debug.lib(cyrus.obj)]  
unresolved external symbol __imp__sasl_dispose referenced in function _ldap_int_sasl_close [oldap32_a_debug.lib(cyrus.obj)]
unresolved external symbol __imp__sasl_errstring referenced in function _ldap_int_sasl_bind [oldap32_a_debug.lib(cyrus.obj)]
```

So my question is, have someone compiled OpenLDAP libraries for UWP succesfully? Is there a more recent documentation on how to do so that I'm missing? Any hint/advice on the topic will be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Could you please check if [this library](https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard) can help?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately that library only works for C# projects.